# How to hide a button on editText click in Android?

Tags: android

I want to hide a button when I click on editText in Android. Initially I was using the following code

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

But for this I need to click on the editText twice. So, to avoid it I made editText focus to false

```
android:focusable="false"
```

and the following code in the OnClickListener of EditText

```
   editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)  getActivity().getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(donationQuantity, 0);

                }
            });
```

In this scenario, I am able to hide the button with one click on editText, but the keyboard doesnot pop up.

Comment: Why not use onFocusChangedListener and see if you get focus ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using setOnTouchListener instead:

```
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of onClick register for OnTouchListener and listen for TouchDown Event,
whenever touchdown event occurs check button Visible/Invisible.

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            editText.setFocusable(true);
            editText.requestFocus();
        }
        return true;

    }
});
```

Comment: It works..Can you tell the difference between onClick and onTouch for editText?

Comment: OnTouch gives the MotionEvent where as onClick event is a complete event comprising of focusing, pressing and releasing.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code to pop up the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```